# How to return link's value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have links with the following structure:

```
<a href="#" class="loadpage">1.1</a>
<a href="#" class="loadpage">1.2</a>
<a href="#" class="loadpage">1.3</a>
```

When the user clicks on this link, I would like to be able to return the correct link clicked and parse out the values before and after the '.'.  Any advice on how to do this with jquery?

```
$('.loadpage').click(function(){
alert('test');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.loadpage').click(function(){
    var vals = $(this).text().split('.');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MrVEA/)**

For example, clicking the second links returns an array of ["1", "2"].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this`

```
$('.loadpage').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("href")); <--Logs the href
    console.log($(this).attr("value")); <--Logs the value (is value a valid attr of a?)
    console.log($(this).text()); <--Logs the link text

    var parts = $(this).text().split("."); <--I believe you want this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '.loadpage' ).click( function(){

    var 
          t = $( this ),
          tv1 = t.text().split( '.' )[ 0 ],
          tv2 = t.text().split( '.' )[ 1 ];

     /*
          now you have you values ready to use
     */
})
```